# Compiling nodejs on solaris 11 fails. File libproc.h not found

Tags: node.js, solaris

I'm trying to compile nodejs en Solaris 11.2 x64 but if fails miserably. A header file named libproc.h is included in on file, but it's not on the filesystem. It seems that long ago it was provided in OpenSolaris, but it's no longer available from Oracle.

Any hint on how to proceed? thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Ricard de Benito

Comment: There's a [github issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6439) about this that you might consider adding your two cents to if you haven't seen it already.

Comment: Thanks mxcdex, right now i'm using the nodejs binary found in this site: http://www.petertribble.co.uk/Solaris/node.html